# How to send Prometheus alerts to SCOM

Tags: integration, monitoring, prometheus-alertmanager, alerts, scom

I want to send Prometheus alerts to SCOM. It seems that there are two ways to accomplish it: with Prometheus webhooks or making SCOM API calls. I think that it is not posible to do it by using SCOM API as there are not an API to create alerts. Regarding the usage of webhook I do not figure out how to do it either.

Is there a way to develop a custom webhook to do this in Prometheus?

Comment: I'm not familiar with SCOM, but it seems like you need an inbound webhook rule in it to receive alerts from alertmanager, and a [`<webhook_config>`](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#webhook_config) on alertmanager's side to send those alerts to SCOM.

Comment: Thank you markalex. I see that is necessary the URL endpoint to send HTTP POST requests to SCOM however I do not found that endpoint in SCOM documentation neither in blogs or any other Internet resource, perhaps it is not possible to do it... definetly this is something quite dark